# How to set Decimal Accuracy in OpenERP?

Tags: openerp-7

I'm new for OpenERP. I want to set decimal accuracy like the product quantity, product price etc.

How i Can set this manually ?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps

- `Setting => Technical => Database Structure => Decimal Accuracy`

From their you can handle and create Decimal Accuracy.

For example If you give digit = 2. it will set 2 decimal accuracy for Usage.

**RML Report format:-**

For Example we take sale order line

`[[ formatLang(line.price_unit , digits=get_digits(dp='Product Price'))]]`

**price_unit** is a field name and **'Product Price'** is a **Usage** name as above you set name.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's works, but i want display that decimal in rml report than what should i do?

Comment: i added my answer and check out that.